# Exception occurrs while opening winforms C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, winforms, entity-framework-6

I've developed a windows application in C#.net and entity framework and database is oracle. I've successfully deployed this application on server machine and application works fine.

When this application is access on client machine then the connection to db is working but when trying to open the form it throws exception-

**"The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid".**

I am using oracle XE and entity frame work 6.0

[image]

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Are you sure the settings for the oracle connection are correct on the client? it says not.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Actually I am executing .exe from client machine and the connection to db is correct

Comment: It could be that the provider is only installed for x86 platform. try to change platform to x64 or viceversa. Or try to install the correct provider on target system.

Comment: How can I change the provider platform? @SebastianSchulz

Comment: Exception text shows that you have issues in your connectionString.

Comment: My application gets connect to database, some forms do open and work but issue is with the forms that uses entity framework. And in my app.config the provider is mention as Oracle.DataAccess.Client.. @Saadi

Comment: Have you added EDMX Data Model in your project?

Comment: Yes I've added the edmx model @Saadi

Comment: Btw: You should set up a global exception handler. Unhandled Exceptions are not very nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project does not seem to know about the provider you are trying to create.  You need to add it to your project's `app.config` file.

For example, here's one for MySQL:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Just change the details to suit the Oracle provider you are using.  I'm not familiar enough to give a more specific example.